# check if two elements exist in array with older browser support

Tags: javascript, performance

Currently I have this code

```
function foo(firstId, secondId){
    var boolOne = false;
    var boolTwo = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var current = arr[i];
        var id = current.id;

        if(firstId == id){
            boolOne = true;
        }

        if(secondId == id){
            boolTwo = true;
        }

        if(boolOne && boolTwo){
            break;
        }
    }

    if(boolOne && boolTwo){
        bar();
    } else {
        // throw error
    }
}
```

I want to check if two objects with the given parameter ids already exist in the array.

I put my code into one for-loop but I could also split the code into two loops and break on a match.

I know I could also use

`var boolOne = arr.includes(item => item.id == firstId)`

but **I have to support the Internet Explorer 9+**. Is there something that can be optimized?

Comment: sorry, IE 9 and later

Comment: What do you mean by optimize? If it´s running faster, your solution is perfect. If you mean code length, it could be reduced but your solutions is clear enough already.

Comment: To call this 'perfect' is a real stretch..

Comment: @konijn perfect performance wise ^^. Your solution fixes all other things :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a short look

- `foo` is a terrible name

  - If this is not the real name, then please do submit the real code
- `arr` seems to be a global, bad practice
- You don't need `current`, you could just go for `var id = arr[i].id;`
- For older browsers, it is faster to cache `arr.length` instead of retrieving it every time
- `bar` is a terrible name, I really hope you don't write production code like that
- the call to `bar` should probably happen outside of that function

Given that, I would go for the below pseudo code:

```
function arrayHasBothObjects(list, id1, id2){
    var boolOne = false,
        boolTwo = false,
        size = list.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        var id = list[i].id;

        boolOne = boolOne || id == id1;
        boolTwo = boolTwo || id == id2;

        if(boolOne && boolTwo){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

- You can solve it using functional approach, which makes code more consice.
- I suggest you to try solve more general problem with **n** identifiers, because arguments names like 'id1' or 'firstId' is a bad smell.

**My solution:**

```
var hasBoth = function(list, id1, id2) {
    return [true, true].toString() === list.reduce(function(res, x) {
        return [id1 === x.id || res[0], id2 === x.id || res[1]];
  }, [false, false]).toString();
}
```